# Mongo merge into array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following:

```
 {_id: blah, anotherId: "externalId", description: "foo"},
 {_id: blah, anotherId: "externalId", description: "bar"},
 ...
```

I want:

```
{_id: blah, anotherId: "externalId", descriptions: ["foo", "bar"]}
```

I know I can simply write this but it's very slow as I have millions of records.

```
db.collectionOfAnotherId.find().forEach(function(r){ 
    var x = {anotherId: r.id, descriptions: []};
    db.myCollection.find({anotherId: x.anotherId}).forEach(function(d){
         x.descriptions.push(d.description); }); 
         db.newCollection.save(x); 
     })
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I am afraid man you'll have to go ahead with idea that you already have in mind. It would be difficult for any DBMS to give facility like that.

Comment: If that description's value was an array since the beginning then you could have had an collective array with all unique elements but...

Comment: Yeah if only the original data was thought out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the aggregation framework for this. For example, consider using the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** operator to do a left join to `myCollection` and writing the results of the following **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline to the new collection using **[`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push)** to create the descriptions array as:

```
db.collectionOfAnotherId.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "myCollection",
            "localField": "id",
            "foreignField": "anotherId",
            "as": "d"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$d" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "anotherId": { "$first": "$id" },
            "descriptions": { "$push": "$d.description" }
        }
    },
    { "$out": "newCollection" }
])
```

Comment: Beautiful! Do you think this will be faster than my simple function. Won't it also have to iterate the data at least twice?

Comment: It could be faster, I don't know but with the aggregation framework it's meant to offer better performance, well it's pretty easy to test so give that a try and see how that fares.